# c++ cmake linking libconfig++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, libconfig

I did install package libconfig with Microsoft/vcpkg manager on Windows. And in Visual Studio trying to link libconfig++ to my project but it can't be linked.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

############ Project name and version
set (TEST_MAJOR_VERSION 1)
set (TEST_MINOR_VERSION 0)
set (TEST_PATCH_VERSION 0)
set (TEST_VERSION ${TEST_MAJOR_VERSION}.${TEST_MINOR_VERSION}.${TEST_PATCH_VERSION})

# Include our cmake macros
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
include (CMakeHelpers)

############ Add projects

# Add main library
add_subdirectory (src)

init_target (test)

if(_version_allowed STREQUAL NEW)
    message (STATUS "==== set project " ${TARGET_NAME})
    project (${TARGET_NAME} VERSION ${TEST_VERSION})
else()
    project (${TARGET_NAME})
endif()


file (GLOB SOURCE_FILES 
    *.cpp)
file (GLOB HEADER_FILES 
    *.h)

find_package(libconfig)

if(WIN32)
    link_directories(G:/_Development/Projects/cpprestsdk/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib)
    include_directories(G:/_Development/Projects/cpprestsdk/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include)
endif()

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE libconfig)
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <libconfig.h++>

using namespace libconfig;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // libconfig
    Config cfg;

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

> > ------ Rebuild started: Project: CMakeLists, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo ------   Cleaning... 0 files.   [1/2]
> >     C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe
> >     /nologo /TP  -IG:_Development\Projects\cppTest\src
> >     -IG:_Development\Projects\cpprestsdk\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include
> >     /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
> >     -std:c++17 /showIncludes /Fosrc\CMakeFiles\test.dir\test.cpp.obj /Fdsrc\CMakeFiles\test.dir\ /FS -c
> >     G:_Development\Projects\cppTest\src\test.cpp
> >     G:_Development\Projects\cpprestsdk\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\libconfig.h++(51):
> >     warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'std::exception' used as base
> >     for dll-interface class 'libconfig::ConfigException'   C:\Program
> >     Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> >     Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime_exception.h(44):
> >     note: see declaration of 'std::exception'
> >     G:_Development\Projects\cpprestsdk\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\libconfig.h++(51):
> >     note: see declaration of 'libconfig::ConfigException'   [2/2] cmd.exe
> >     /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> >     Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"
> >     -E vs_link_exe --intdir=src\CMakeFiles\test.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> >     /nologo src\CMakeFiles\test.dir\test.cpp.obj  /out:src\test.exe
> >     /implib:src\test.lib /pdb:src\test.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64
> >     /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console
> >     -LIBPATH:G:_Development\Projects\cpprestsdk\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib
> >     libconfig.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib
> >     shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
> >     && cd ."   FAILED: src/test.exe    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program
> >     Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> >     Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"
> >     -E vs_link_exe --intdir=src\CMakeFiles\test.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> >     /nologo src\CMakeFiles\test.dir\test.cpp.obj  /out:src\test.exe
> >     /implib:src\test.lib /pdb:src\test.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64
> >     /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console
> >     -LIBPATH:G:_Development\Projects\cpprestsdk\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib
> >     libconfig.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib
> >     shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
> >     && cd ."   LINK Pass 1: command
> >     "C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> >     /nologo src\CMakeFiles\test.dir\test.cpp.obj /out:src\test.exe
> >     /implib:src\test.lib /pdb:src\test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64
> >     /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console
> >     -LIBPATH:G:_Development\Projects\cpprestsdk\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib
> >     libconfig.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib
> >     shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
> >     /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:src\CMakeFiles\test.dir/intermediate.manifest
> >     src\CMakeFiles\test.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the
> >     following output: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> >     Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\test.cpp.obj : error LNK2019:
> >     unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl
> >     libconfig::Config::Config(void)" (__imp_??0Config@libconfig@@QEAA@XZ)
> >     referenced in function main C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> >     Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\test.cpp.obj : error LNK2019:
> >     unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual
> >     __cdecl libconfig::Config::~Config(void)" (__imp_??1Config@libconfig@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
> >     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> >     Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\src\test.exe : fatal error
> >     LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   ninja: build stopped: subcommand
> >     failed.
>
> Build failed.

What is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `libconfig` (C library) is not the same as `libconfig++`

Comment: yes, right, i did change to `find_package(libconfig++)` and seems compilation works but VS still do not recognize `#include <libconfig.h++>` as header file, it propose `.h`. Why?